# Duplicate Characters Removal - From O(n^2) to O(n)

Tags: c, time-complexity

C program for removal of duplicate characters from the given string. It uses the O(n2) can we do it in O(n) order. Please comment on this program.

```
int main()
{

 char a[100],b[100],temp='\0';

  int i,n,j,count=0,p=0,k=0;

 printf("ENTRE THE STRING \n");

 scanf("%s",a);

 n = strlen(a);

 i=0;

 while(i < n)
 {

   count=0;

    temp = a[i];

   for(j = i  ; j  < n ; j++ )
    {

      if(temp==a[j])
       {
         count++;
       }
   }

  if(count<2) 
   {

     b[k] = temp;

     k++;
   } 

   i++;

 }

 b[k]='\0';

 printf("THE RESULTED STRING IS \n");

 for(p = 0 ; p < k ; p++)

 printf("%c ",b[p]);

 printf("\n");

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why do you think your while loop "uses the O(n2)"?

Comment: @VolAnd Notice the code inside `while` loop, the OP runs `for(j = i  ; j  < n ; j++ )` which is akin to a O(n) code.

Comment: you mean n^2? o.k. I understand now, sorry for my carelessness

Comment: Yes, you can do it in O(n). You can even do it in-place if desired. [See it live](http://ideone.com/vpk2gf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can** create a `O(n)` algorithm for this.

Steps:

1. Create another array `bucket[]` with size 255. (Should adjust all the characters)
2. Initialise every element in `bucket[]` to `0`.
3. Run a loop and increment the `bucket[]` at the index `a[i]`.
4. Now, run another loop through the `bucket[]`, if `bucket[i] > 0`, append the `(char) i` to the `b[]` array.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[100], b[100];
    int bucket[256] = {0};
    int i;
    printf("Enter the string:");
    scanf("%s",a);
    int n = strlen(a);
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        //Incrementing the character count of each character.
        bucket[a[i]]++;
    }
    //Keep track of the index where the next character is to be appended.
    int b_pos = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        //Character occurs in a[], we don't care if it occurs once 
        //or twice, we just need one instance of it.
        if (bucket[i] > 0)
        {
            b[b_pos] = (char) i;
            b_pos++;
        }
    }
    b[b_pos] = '\0';
    printf("Modified string : %s",b);
}
```

Comment: Easier way to Initializing bucket[] to 0 is ` int bucket[256] = {0};`

Comment: Yes, we can do that for sure. I'll change it.

Comment: Fyi, you don't need the second loop. Everything here can be done in a single loop, and in fact a single *buffer* should the need arise to do this in-place.

Comment: I've seen your code, which is wonderful, but this code was intended to be *beginner-friendly*. You are absolutely right this code could be more efficient, but my aim was to give the OP a gist of this method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
int main()
{

 char a[100],b[100];

  int i,n,j,count=0,k=0;

 printf("ENTRE THE STRING \n");

 scanf("%s",a);

 n = strlen(a);

b[0] = a[0];
k = 1;
for(i=1;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        if(a[i] == b[j])
        {
            count = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(count == 0)
    {
        b[k] = a[i];
        k++;
    }
    else
    {
        count = 0;
    }

}
b[k] = 0;

printf("RESULT %s",b);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is still a O(n^2) algorithm.

Comment: @shauryachats This is surely not O(n^2) algorithm.`for(j=0;j<i;j++)` is not '`for(j=0;j<n;j++)`

Comment: But `i` does vary from 1 to `n`. And if you sum up the total number of executions inside the `for(j=0;j<n;j++) `, it would be `1+2+3+4...+n` which is equal to `n * (n+1) / 2` or `(n^2 + n)/2`, which is still O(n^2).

Comment: for large `n` the loop count reaches to `(n^2/2)`

Comment: So? It is still O(n^2).